# Выяснить, в какой строке последовательность является возрастающей или убывающей. python

Tags: python

Задача: Дан целочисленный двумерный массив, размерности N х M. Выяснить, в какой строке последовательность является возрастающей или убывающей.
Мой код:

```
import random

N = int(input('Количество строк:'))

M = int(input('Количество столбцов:'))
 
A = [[0] * M for i in range(N)]
 
for i in range(N):

    for j in range(M):

        A[i][j] = random.randint(0, 10)
 
for i in A:

        print(f'{i}', end='')
        print()

for i in range(N):

    for j in range(M):
        if A[i]>A[i+1]:
            print ('строка уменьшается')
```

Не могу понять, как пройтись по каждой строке и определить там, где убывает, а где возрастает. Пытался как-то пройтись по массиву, но ничего не вышло толкового.

Comment: не стал писать код, когда строка может уменьшается, ибо и при проверке уменьшения нормально не работало

Comment: Я бы предложил отсортировать строку и сравнивать с оригинальной, но возникает вопрос: каждая строка имеют один вид последовательности? Или в одной строке может быть и возрастающая, и убывающая? Для второго варианта непонятно как определять: по длине, по количеству последовательностей

Comment: числа в строке могут быть разными, то есть могут и возрастать и убывать

Comment: Вы не поняли, вот берем строку: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]. Вот тут что возрастание или убывание? :) У вас массив заполняется случайно, поэтому такие случаи будут возникать постоянно

Comment: если такой случай, то ничего выводить не должно. нужно найти строки, где с первого элемента идет или убывание, или возрастание

Answer (score 3):

Строка убывает, если каждый элемент меньше предыдущего.

Строка возрастает, если каждый элемент больше предыдущего.

Поэтому нужно не просто проверять два соседних элемента, как в вашем коде, а еще и "держать в памяти" предыдущее состояние. Ведь если каждый элемент меньше предыдущего, но самый последний вдруг больше предпоследнего, то строка уже не является убывающей.

Comment: а каким образом это можно сделать, не подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

можете сделать так, хотя, с точки зрения эффективности, это не лучший вариант:

```
from random import choices

n = 5 #int(input('Количество строк:'))
m = 5 #int(input('Количество столбцов:'))
a = [choices(range(10), k=m) for i in range(n)]

for i in a:
    if all(x>=y for x,y in zip(i,i[1:])):
        print('строка убывает')
    elif all(x<=y for x,y in zip(i,i[1:])):
        print('строка возрастает')
    else:
        print('строка не упорядочена')
```

Comment: строго говоря, для возрастающей и убывающей последовательностей знак должен быть строго > или <. А если <= или >=, то это неубывающая/невозрастающая последовательность.

Comment: @Эникейщик, полностью согласен.